# how to get a distinct value when the columns have different data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below table

```
KEY    WO#    Parts   Name
77     11     1       aa
77     11     2       aa
81     12     2       bb
82     9      3       cc
```

Now i want to write a query for my report so that whenever theres a duplicate RKEY i want it to ignore it even though the number of parts in the duplicate RKEY are different and proceed with the next RKEY. Is this possible

End result

```
KEY    WO#    Parts   Name
77     11     1       aa
81     12     2       bb
82     9      3       cc
```

Comment: Use a `group by` clause. Post your query in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: I´m sorry... I didn't realize it wasn't MySQL. Answer deleted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked and answered literally hundreds of times. But it is faster to type out a solution than find an existing answer.

```
select [KEY]
    , [WO#]
    , Parts
    , Name
from
(
    select [KEY]
        , [WO#]
        , Parts
        , Name
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by KEY order by Parts)
    from YourTable
) x
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I live for the day I earn the dupe hammer in Sql-Server.

Answer (score -1):

EatPeanutButter is correct: If you use the 'group by' command on 'Key', only the first instance of 'Key' will be shown in the end result.

```
select * from table group by Key;
```

Comment: This query will not provide the desired results in the question.   In fact, it will result in an error.